# wrong number of arguments error while trying to save?

Tags: excel, vba

I keep getting a `wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment` error when trying to tack on a `password:="xxxxxx"` at the end of this line of code.

```
Wb.SaveCopyAs ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & _
          ValidFileName(Login & " - " & Last & " - " & "Move to $15" & ".xlsx"), Password:="xxxxxx"
```

What could be causing this? The files saved fine beforehand, but stopped with that error once I tried including a password.

Answer (score 3):

[SaveCopyAs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.savecopyas) doesn't take a password parameter. Only a filename.

> Syntax expression. SaveCopyAs( *Filename* )
>
> expression A variable that represents a Workbook object.
>
> Parameters Name   Required/Optional   Data type   Description
>   Filename  Required    Variant Specifies the file name for the copy.

Comment: Did this answer your question please?